# How can i protect N-MOSFET from failing

Tags: troubleshooting

i have made simple inverter circuit with **z44 MOSFET** but circuit work for minutes and the primary coil start heating then shorting finally damage the MOSFETF, it is my 6th time facing this issue. i have no idea how to protect the MOSFET. Why this is happening and is there anything i have to improve ?

any idea would helpful

thanks!!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fareGY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Heatsink your MOSFETs. Also, they are probably switching on and off too slow due to the high resistances at the gate which means a lot of time spent as resistors dissipating power. It would help if you knew the frequency it was running at and the peak current.

Comment: Do you have a scope? How did you design the transformer? What's its primary inductance? What is the switching frequency? Have you measured the supply current with no load?

Comment: Your circuit also appears assymetrical. Is this intentional?

Comment: You might want to connect M2 source to GND.

Comment: i have heatsinked them with fan ,actually they are not heating as i expected they just working and the transfromer's primary coil heat , melt and finally start shorting @DKNguyen

Comment: @BrianDrummond i have orderd fly back driver but have used fly zapper transformer for test https://i.stack.imgur.com/neLBc.jpg and it works 5 times powerful with it`s volt, current and frequency than it's driver

Comment: @BrianDrummond i forget to add in this circuit but i have added in my circuit

Comment: First, you need a scope to check the frequency, drain-source votlages and drain currents. The gate voltages for the MOSFETs are 6VDC (due to 1k-1k divider). Check the Vds-Id graphs from [this document](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3a9f220d) (Fig.2). Maybe there's a lot of dissipation for your current-voltage levels.

Comment: @RohatKılıç so i have to upgrade  R2 and R4 resistance to 2kohm

Comment: In my opinion: your circuit is just **too simple** to **properly switch on/off those MOSFETs** meaning they're "half conducting" most of the time and that means they will be dissipating a lot of heat. There might be **voltage spikes** as well that damage them. Instead of "protecting the MOSFETs" you should be looking at a **much much better design**. If you'd care to study commercial inverters and how they're build then you'd learn that no inverter is build like this. The reason is simple: because it doesn't work reliably enough.

Comment: Step 1: Figure out *why* it's failing. Step 2: Fix that. Is it simply overheating? Are you exceeding the voltage or current limits? Is the transformer core saturating causing the current to be higher than you thought?

Answer (score 4):

> *Why this is happening and is there anything i have to improve ?*

Your circuit has no fly-back protection circuit to prevent back emfs from transformer primary leakage inductance. It's crucial that some form of protection be applied if you are to avoid voltage fly-back exceeding the limit on the IRFZ44 MOSFETs (55 volts but no more).

[image]

The above is an example of a snubber that dissipates the energy from the leakage inductance.

Comment: @DKNguyen no, not diodes to centre point. The centre-point is the fulcrum of a seesaw. When one end goes down to 0 volts, the other end rises up to twice Vcc and the leakage spike is on top of that. Transformer action!

Comment: Oh yeah. You're right. It isn't just a dead half winding during the other cycle. You would need bidirectional TVS clamp diodes, not unidirectional diodes.

Comment: So I have to add rc snubber circuit, but it have effect on the frequency

Comment: It needs calculating properly. Like, how much resistance can snub the spike to below the peak limit of the MOSFET and like, how little capacitance can be in series without making the snubber ineffective.